# SQL Connect Via PHP

Tags: php, sql, connection

```
   $serverName = "172.20.90.100"; 

   // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
   // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.

   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"correctdb");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
   echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
   echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
```

this is giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() On LINE 23

I was wondering what I should change to establish a connection.

Comment: there's not 23 lines there?

Comment: @rowlandshaw I copied this part out the other part was commented code

Answer (score 3):

[`sqlsrv_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) is a php function embedded in the SQL server extension. The error shows you haven't enabled it yet.

You have to enable the extension. How this is done is described [here in the manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/de/sqlsrv.installation.php)

Comment: @Bjoem If you're not busy, is it possible for us to set up a chat, i just have a few quick questions to ask you.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098) if you haven't already.
- Make sure you have these lines in your `php.ini`:

  ```
  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
  extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
  ```

Documentation: **[`sqlsrv_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/sqlsrv.installation.php)**

Comment: is it possible for us to set up a chat? I just want to ask a few questions.